# Error loading image from presistent Uri

Tags: java, android, image, permissions

The program flow is that the user selects an image from the gallery and it is displayed in an image view. This works fine. At the same time, the Uri is written to a database.

Later, when the program is run again or that activity is displayed again, the Uri is retrieved from the database and the image is displayed again. This second showing of the image is what causes the exception:

```
requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
```

I added the permission to the manifest and the exception still occurs.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

The same procedure attempts to display both images, and it works when it comes from the picker, but fails when it comes from the presistent Uri from the database.

Picker Intent

```
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                PICK_IMAGE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

With the result from the picker intent I use

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
```

With the database read I use. localImage is a String.

```
Uri.parse(localImage)
```

I read this bug report https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5398, but I'm not sure how to use it to resolve this situation. The code below from another thread seems to attempt to resolve a similar issue with permissions and the photo picker, but in my case I'm not picking again, I just need to display the image from the Uri.

I guess it is a matter of resetting permissions. I'm not really sure. I have the permissions in the manifest. Perhaps I need different code to display an image from a Uri not obtained from the picker? Maybe I need to target a different API? My build.gradle says targetSdkVersion 21, minSdkVersion 15. These were the defaults. I'm in Android Studio 1.0.2.

I'm stumped. Any help is appreciated.

```
public static final String KITKAT_VALUE = 1002;

    Intent intent;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
                            intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            intent.setType("*/*");
                            startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);
                        } else {
                            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                            intent.setType("*/*");
                            startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);
                    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == KITKAT_VALUE ) {
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             // do something here
         }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the same time, the Uri is written to a database.

That's not going to work prior to API Level 19, and then only if you are using the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`) and take the offered persistent permissions. Given your existing code, the temporary permissions that you are granted for that `Uri` will expire, at the latest when your process is terminated.

> I added the permission to the manifest and the exception still occurs.

You cannot hold `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS`, unless you are signed by the signing key that signed the firmware.

Comment: I assume when you say, use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT you mean with an intent. I use MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), selectedImage) to open the image, not an intent.

Comment: @user1091524: "I use MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), selectedImage) to open the image, not an intent" -- only after you get the `Uri`. Depending on which piece of code in your question that you are using, you are getting that `Uri` via `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and/or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. In the latter case, you can attempt to [persist permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#permissions), if the storage provider offers them.

Comment: Yes, long after. Getting the Uri the first time is not an issue. that works. The exception only occurs the second time, after permissions have been lost. I thought you were some how implying I could use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT on that second attempt, which didn't make sense. Thank you for the link on persistent permissions. Would I have have this same problem for images my app writes to the SD storage?

Comment: @user1091524: "Would I have have this same problem for images my app writes to the SD storage?" -- if you were able to write it to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) or [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), you will be able to read it in using the same filesystem path as before, assuming that the user didn't move it in the meantime.